# Can variables be passed to a SQL*Loader control file via sqlldr command?

Tags: oracle, sql-loader, controlfile

Below is my Control file example :

```
    OPTIONS (skip=1,errors=1000,direct=true,rows=10000)
    load data 
    append
    into table TABLE_NAME
    fields terminated by ','
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    trailing nullcols(
      DATE_ID       DATE_ID_VALUE,
      DESC1         char(1000),
      DESC2         char(1000),
      DISP_URL      char(1000),
      DEST_URL      char(1000),
      ACCT_ID       ACCOUNTID_VALUE,
      Acct_num      ACCOUNT_NUM,
      created_date SYSDATE
    )
```

I need to pass DATE_ID_VALUE,ACCOUNTID, ACCOUNTNUM values from sqlldr command. Am passing the remaming columns data via csv file which inturn is passed from sqlldr "DATA" parameter. Is there a way to pass other required parameters via sqlldr command or any other way to do it?

Below is my sqlldr command :

```
   sqlldr userid=abc/abcdef@abcdefgh CONTROL= cont.ctl DATA= $csvFilePath  LOG=admaster.log BAD=admaster.bad
```

Comment: You can create customized control file on-the-fly just before invoking SQLLoader

Comment: i dont want to create new control file for each upload, so i decided to make it parametrized ...

Comment: You _can't_ make it parameterised though @arul... so you're going to have to do it differently. If you're trying to add a constant why not just create a view on the table or select that data in your application. There's no need to add it to the ctl file.

Comment: Thks guys for ur replies ... Let me tell you the process in my application, User will create a project first from which i get account_id(Project Name) and account_num(last inserted id), using these two values i need to insert csv data to tables using sqlldr control file. Now pls suggest me how it can be done ... 
NOTE: for each project there are 4 csv files to be uploaded, so i think creating new control files for each project is not an effecient way...

Comment: You could potentially append the fixed values to each row of the CSV file instead, but that will be slower and use more space than creating a temporary control file. What is the problem with creating a new control file, and then deleting it again immediately after the load?

Comment: Let me try it. can u guide me how can i create control file dynamically using php ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I just stumbled on it and I recently answered a similar question.  Please see my reply here for a technique to create a control file from a wrapper program.

[insert timestanp of INFILE into a column from SQLLOADER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250002/insert-timestanp-of-infile-into-a-column-from-sqlloader/27280827#27280827)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to parameterise the variables in the .ctl file, but it is possible to dispense with a .ctl file altogether and parameterise whatever you want.

Rather than calling sqlldr directly, you need to declare an external table, then do a SQL `INSERT into TABLE_NAME SELECT * from EXTERNAL_TABLE;`.  The external table declaration contains the sqlldr parameters that are used behind the scenes, and is defined in a SQL query which can be run directly from the Unix shell, with all the required parameters specified as Unix system variables or commands.

E.g. having set the values of $DATE_ID_VALUE and the other 2 variables in your calling environment, first create an external table:

```
echo "create table myschema.temp_table_name (
    DATE_ID       INTEGER,
    DESC1         char(1000),
    DESC2         char(1000),
    DISP_URL      char(1000),
    DEST_URL      char(1000),
    ACCT_ID       INTEGER,
    Acct_num      INTEGER,
    created_date  DATE)
   organization external
     (
     type oracle_loader
     default directory mydir
     access parameters (
       records delimited by newline
       badfile bad_dir: 'temp_ext_temp_table_name_load.bad'
       logfile log_dir: 'temp_ext_temp_table_name_load.log'
       fields terminated by ',' (
          DESC1         char(1000),
          DESC2         char(1000),
          DISP_URL      char(1000),
          DEST_URL      char(1000)
       )
       column transforms (
          DATE_ID       FROM CONSTANT '$DATE_ID_VALUE',
          ACCT_ID       FROM CONSTANT '$ACCOUNTID_VALUE',
          Acct_num      FROM CONSTANT '$ACCOUNT_NUM',
          created_date  FROM CONSTANT \"`date '+%d-%b-%Y'`\"
       )
     )
     location ('temp_table_name.dat')
     )
     reject limit 1000;" | sqlplus -s /
```

The `column transforms` clause will populate the external table with the constant values resolved from your environment variables and the Unix date command.

Then do the insert into the target table (optional `append` hint for direct path load):

```
insert /*+ append */ into table_name
select * from myschema.temp_table_name;
```

I couldn't find a way to include SYSDATE, so used the Unix date command equivalent instead.