# Is it possible to pass user-defined variables to Sqlldr command?

Tags: oracle11g, sql-loader

I need to pass a user-defined value to control file. Say for example, I have a variable named `MyVar` , how can I pass this to sqlldr command?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how are you calling sqlldr? and where is this variable coming from?

Comment: I will be calling it from shell script. This variable will be defined in shell script. And the value will be either hard coded or will be fetched from database dynamically.

Comment: Will the variable be used to populate a column in the load?  You can't pass a variable in but there are other ways depending on what you are trying to do.  Please add some more detail.

Comment: @Gary_W , Thanks for your reply, I went through one of your answers and it helped me. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250002/insert-timestanp-of-infile-into-a-column-from-sqlloader/27280827#27280827)

Comment: That's the one I was going to refer you to once you provided more detail on what you were trying to do.  Glad it helped.  Once you get it figured out, please post what worked for you here so all can benefit from your experience.